# Parsing through dictionary and updating blanks in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

Please look at the following dataframe:

```
      A     B
0     Fruit Apple
1     Car   BMW
2           Cat
```

Dictionary: `{'Apple': 'Fruit', 'BMW':'Car','Cat': 'Animal'}`

Desired output:

```
      A      B
0     Fruit  Apple
1     Car    BMW
2     Animal Cat
```

My thinking:

1. Parse through column A
2. Identify blank values
3. For each blank value, look at corresponding row element in Column 'B' (ex: "" -> "Cat")
4. Get the value from that row and use as a key for a defined dictionary labeled "Dictionary"
5. Use the output value from the key-value pair and replace the blank value with the output value from dictionary

if someone could please help me code this in python that would be great :)

Comment: What is the issue, which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

If your DataFrame and dictionary are named `df` and `d`, try this:

```
# Map column B to values of the dictionary
mapper = df['B'].map(d)

# Replace empty strings in A with corresponding dict-mapped value
df['A'] = df['A'].replace('', np.nan).fillna(mapper)

df
        A      B
0   Fruit  Apple
1     Car    BMW
2  Animal    Cat
```